# Trying to echo contents of multiple text files while sorting the output by the file name - PHP

Tags: php, sorting, file-get-contents, opendir, readdir

I'm not a developer, but I'm the default developer at work now.  : )  Over the last few weeks I've found a lot of my answers here and at other sites, but this latest problem has me confused beyond belief. I KNOW it's a simple answer, but I'm not asking Google the right questions.

First... I have to use text files, as I don't have access to a database (things are locked down TIGHT where I work).

Anyway, I need to look into a directory for text files stored there, open each file and display a small amount of text, while making sure the text I display is sorted by the file name.

I'm CLOSE, I know it... I finally managed to figure out sorting, and I know how to read into a directory and display the contents of the files, but I'm having a heck of a time merging those two concepts together.

Can anyone provide a bit of help? With the script as it is now, I echo the sorted file names with no problem. My line of code that I thought would read the contents of a file and then display it is only echoing the line breaks, but not the contents of the files. This is the code I've got so far - it's just test code so I can get the functionality working.

```
<?php
$dirFiles = array();
if ($handle = opendir('./event-titles')) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
            $dirFiles[] = $file;
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
sort($dirFiles);
foreach($dirFiles as $file)
{
    $fileContents = file_get_contents($file);//////// This is what's not working
    echo $file."<br>".$fileContents."<br/><br/>";
}
?>
```

Help?  : )

Dave

Comment: By the way, if I somehow messed up the original post when entering the code, I apologize.

Comment: `file_get_contents` can't find the file by just its name, you have to use `file_get_contents("./event-titles/$file")` as @Greg suggested on his answer.

Answer (score 1):

`$files = scandir('./event-titles')` will return an array of filenames in filename-sorted order. You can then do

```
foreach($files as $file)
{
    $fileContents = file_get_contents('./event-titles/'.$file);
    echo $file."<br/>".$fileContents."<br/><br/>";
}
```

Note that I use the directory name in the file_get_contents call, as the filename by itself will cause file_get_contents to look in the current directory, not the directory you were specifying in scandir.

Comment: For some reason, that's giving me a blank return. I understand the logic behind it though, believe it or not.  ; )   (You don't know me, but you wouldn't believe I understood this if you did know me. ; )   )